# session_start() causing empty $_POST after form submission

Tags: php, forms, session

I am testing my page which has a very simple form:

```
<form action="script/check.php" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = "email">
    <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

When my `check.php` file has the following code, it works fine:

```
<? 
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

The output is `array(1) { ["email"]=> string(5) "hello" }`, as expected.

When `check.php` includes `session_start()`, `$_POST` becomes empty.

```
<?
session_start();
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

The output is now `array(0) { }`.

It's difficult to search for this problem, unfortunately most of the results I find online with these search terms are about empty `$_SESSION` variables, which is not a problem for me. The problem is `$_POST` is empty.

There is a catch: `$_POST` goes through correctly when I test the page from a local machine, on the network where the server is stored. For everywhere else, this is not the case, the site is unworkable. This is extremely odd as I've been using scripts of this type for months without any problem, and outside users have been able to connect without issue. I'm thinking it's a directory permission problem, but I can't be sure without more information.

Comment: What kind of server do you on? Is it a local server?

Comment: Just ran your exact code given with `session_start` on local stack, got back `array(1) { ["email"]=> string(4) "test" }` Do you have it set to display_errors?

Comment: is this on-line? i would like to test it checking the http headers

Comment: are errors shown in your server? There's no black magic behind PHP, as far as I know session_start() has nothing to do with $_POST.

Comment: `display_errors` is off. The server is online, and has a number of working pages with the same code.

Comment: starting a session **MAY** cause a redirect, which'd be done via a GET, meaning POST data is lost. You can verify this easily by using something like firefox's firebug nettab or the httpfox extension, and see if there's any redirects occuring.

Comment: Hey, there is a complaint about this on the doc comments. Check if `print_r($_REQUEST)` works. is `register_globals` on?

Comment: @Anthony `print_r($_REQUEST)` returns Array `( [email] => test [PHPSESSID] => <hex number> )` on my local machine, and 
`Array ( [PHPSESSID] => <hex number> )` on the remote machine. I'm not sure if this helps determine the problem. (edit: the <hex number> is a 32-character string of hex numbers and letters)

Comment: Do you have session_start() on the page that the POST originated from?

Comment: @BarryChapman No, it is an HTML page. `register_globals` is off, I'm going to download nettab now and check if a redirect is occurring.

Comment: Okay, so I added both `ini_set ('register_globals', '1');` and `ini_set ('display_errors', '1');` to the line under `session_start();` and the page now works correctly. I apparently need both, without both it does not work. If anyone can post a reason for this, I'll accept it as an answer... but for now mystery solved? I guess...? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please, NEVER enable register_globals. You dont need it, it is a major security hole and it is already deprecated and will stop working.
Rgister globals has nothing to do with $_POST but would create global variables for anything posted.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: Just put session_start(); in script, where is form. Also you can enable session autostart in php.ini and turn off register_globals

Answer (score 1):

..had the same problem too. The reason for the empty $_SESSION-vars were the incorrect rights in the /var/lib/php/session directory: 755 owner + group the user which runs the http (apache, www-data or cherokee)

Comment: @SaurabhSinha: please do not repeat NAA and invalid without reasons. Be more concrete to be actually useful.

Comment: @Laszlo Papp: is this answer in context?

Comment: @SaurabhSinha: you claimed something. You _are_ supposed to explain your stuff.

Comment: @Laszlo Papp: ok now i got your point. I need to explain on the comments posted. Isn't It.. Will keep in mind from next time.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The things happening is due to session, You need to check session already started or not.

```
<?
if(!isset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]))
{
  session_start();
  var_dump($_POST);
}else{
    var_dump($_POST);
}  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your php.ini file for short tags, because you are using php short tags which is discouraged. Please check your php.ini file and enable --enable-short-tags option if you want to use short tags `<? ?>`. I strongly recommends you to use `<?php ?>` tags. With proper php tags your code is works fine.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php